# How to change button textcolor based on the data stored in the firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently doing my project on parking system in Android using Firebase.

[image]

This is my output showing slots in a parking lot..

Each button in this output represent a slot in a lot. These buttons are dynamically created based on the ‘number of slots’ (SlotNo4 in AllSlot collection) stored in the database for each lot..

I want these buttons text color to be in black if the slots are “available” (as provided in the database for each slot (SStatus in AllSlot collection)) and to be in RED if the slot is already “occupied” by a vehicle and to be in YELLOW if the slot is “booked”.

But I can't make it out..as you can see in the output only 'S5’ is shown in yellow colour..the rest of the slots(buttons) textcolors are not changed..PLEASE HELP ME

[image]

This is my Firebase database collection (AllSlot) for the slot details..

[image]

Database screenshot continuation

This is my code.

```
public class SlotActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    LinearLayout parent1, parent2, parent3, parent4;
    Button b;
    String m = Prevalent1.currentsearchslot.getSlotNo4();
    int n = Integer.parseInt(m);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AllSlot").
            child(Prevalent1.currentsearchslot.getLID());




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slot);

        parent1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_parent);
        parent2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_parent2);
        parent3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_parent3);
        parent4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_parent4);


        for (int i = 0; i < n / 4; i++) {
            b = new Button(SlotActivity.this);
            b.setId(i + 1);
            b.setText("S" + (i + 1));
            slotdb(b.getId());
            parent1.addView(b);
            b.setOnClickListener(SlotActivity.this);

        }

        for (int i = n / 4; i < n / 2; i++) {
            b = new Button(SlotActivity.this);
            b.setId(i + 1);
            b.setText("S" + (i + 1));
            slotdb(b.getId());
            parent2.addView(b);
            b.setOnClickListener(SlotActivity.this);

        }
        for (int i = n / 2; i < 3 * n / 4; i++) {
            b = new Button(SlotActivity.this);
            b.setId(i + 1);
            b.setText("S" + (i + 1));
            slotdb(b.getId());
            parent3.addView(b);
            b.setOnClickListener(SlotActivity.this);

        }

        for (int i = 3 * n / 4; i < n; i++) {
            b = new Button(SlotActivity.this);
            b.setId(i + 1);
            b.setText("S" + (i + 1));
            slotdb(b.getId());
            parent4.addView(b);
            b.setOnClickListener(SlotActivity.this);

        }

    }




    private void slotdb(final int id) {

        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AllSlot").
                child(Prevalent1.currentsearchslot.getLID());

         final String sid = String.valueOf(id);

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!(dataSnapshot.child(sid).exists())) {

                    HashMap<String, Object> userdataMap = new HashMap<>();
                    userdataMap.put("SID", sid);
                    userdataMap.put("SStatus", "Available");

                    ref.child(sid).updateChildren(userdataMap);

                } else {

                    if (dataSnapshot.child(sid).child("SStatus").exists()) {

                        if ((dataSnapshot.child(sid).child("SStatus")).getValue().equals("Occupied")) {


                            b.setTextColor(Color.RED);


                        } else if ((dataSnapshot.child(sid).child("SStatus")).getValue().equals("Booked")) {

                            b.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

                        } else {

                            b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {

        view.getId();
        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AllSlot").
                child(Prevalent1.currentsearchslot.getLID());
        final int a = view.getId();


        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(a)).exists()) {

                    SingleSlot data = dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(a)).getValue(SingleSlot.class);

                    if (data.getSID().equals(String.valueOf(a))) {

                        Prevalent2.currentclickedslot = data;


                        if (Prevalent2.currentclickedslot.getSStatus().equals("Available")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Available!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            Intent intent = new Intent(SlotActivity.this, BookInfo.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else if (Prevalent2.currentclickedslot.getSStatus().equals("Occupied")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Occupied!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This Slot is already Booked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }


                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a method something like:

```
private void changeTextColor(LinearLayout layout, int color) {
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof Button) {
        v.setTextColor(color);
    }
 }
}
```

And call it for all your parent layouts, why ur approach is not working because u have a global variable b and u are just assigning a new button to it every time and losing the old references.